# Is there no text vertical align property in famo.us?

Tags: vertical-alignment, famo.us

It looks like in all the famo.us examples they use a really big `lineHeight` property to vertically align the text on a surface to the middle, whereas they use `textAlign: "center"` to align it horizontally.  That seems problematic if there is no vertical align because if I want a paragraph of text the line height trick will screw that up.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be an easier question than it is but because of an issue with true-sizing surfaces, you may need to pull together a hack for this one.

The issue is that true-sized surfaces, cannot report their height to modifiers for properly calculating position at a given origin. You will have to set the actual height of the surface in order to achieve true centering.

In this example, The surface is centered in the entire context based on the size of the content. I subclassed the Surface so I could redefine deploy which takes the target element as the argument. I then set the size of the surface.state so that with its origin, it is able to center the element.

These are the types of issues that will be fixed soon, but a hack will have to do for now..

Here is the example.. Good Luck

```
var Engine            = require('famous/core/Engine');
var Surface           = require('famous/core/Surface');
var StateModifier     = require('famous/modifiers/StateModifier');

function MySurface(options) {
    Surface.apply(this, arguments);
    this._superDeploy = Surface.prototype.deploy
}

MySurface.prototype = Object.create(Surface.prototype);
MySurface.prototype.constructor = MySurface;

MySurface.prototype.deploy = function deploy(target) {
  this._superDeploy(target);
  var size    = this.getSize();
  var width   = size[0] == true ? target.offsetWidth  : size[0] ;
  var height  = size[1] == true ? target.offsetHeight : size[1] ;
  this.state.setSize([width,height]);
};


var context = Engine.createContext();

var lorem = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodoconsequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit essecillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.";

var surface = new MySurface({
  size: [200,true],
  content: lorem,
  properties: {
    color: 'white',
    textAlign: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'green'
  }
});

surface.state = new StateModifier({origin:[0.5,0.5]});

context.add(surface.state).add(surface);
```

Comment: I don't fully understand how this works.  Where are you setting the vertical text alignment of `middle`?  Does that just happen because you set the origin to `[0.5,0.5]`?  If so, wouldn't that affect other aspects like how the surface behaves when it is rotated, etc.?  I.e. what if I wanted to center the text but have it still rotate about the upper-left corner?  Thank you!

Comment: Yes it would affect other elements under that modifier. The [0.5,0.5] modifier is used only on the text.. Look at my example and on the last line.. imagine I add surface.state and surface to a View or RenderNode instead of the context. This new View or RenderNode can then be attached to the context with it's own modifier for rotating.